# Java Interop: Why does (.setProperty (Properties.) "key1" "value1") return nil but wrapping the call in a doto works?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

The following code returns nil:

```
(.setProperty (Properties.) "key1" "value1") -> nil
```

The following, however, seems to work as intended:

```
(doto (Properties.) (.setProperty "key1" "value1")) -> {"key1" "value1"}
```

Why is that?

Comment: You can figure out it by macro expansion. `doto` is macro. If you tried to macro expansion to `doto` form, you can see expand result, like this `(let [G__85037 (Properties.)] (.setProperty G__85037 "key1" "value1") G__85037)` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.setProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)returns the previous value, or `null` if one did not exist. Since it is operating on a new `Properties` instance, this is `nil`. `(doto x f)` evaluates `f` with `x` in the first argument position and then returns `x`. In this case the `nil` returned by `setProperty` is ignored and the modified `Properties` instance is returned.

Answer (score 1):

The first form evalutes to the return value of the method call.

The second form evaluates to the object instance after running the method call as a side effect.